# Converting genetic matrix to STRUCTURE

Tags: r, file-formats, phylogenetics

I want to convert a genetic matrix (rows are samples, columns are alleles) into a STRUCTURE file (output .str) within R. Is there a preferred way to achieve this? I've found [genind_to_structure](https://rdrr.io/cran/graph4lg/man/genind_to_structure.html) in the [graph4lg](https://rdrr.io/cran/graph4lg/) R package, but I wanted to see if there are other approaches.

An example of what I mean by a "genetic matrix":

```
# Build a matrix of alleles
temp <- lapply(1:30, function(i) sample(1:9, 4, replace = TRUE))
temp <- sapply(temp, paste, collapse="")
temp <- matrix(temp, nrow = 10, dimnames = list(paste("ind",1:10), paste("loc",1:3)))
temp

# Convert matrix to genind format (for adegenet package)
test <- df2genind(temp, ploidy = 4, sep = "")
test

# How to convert to STRUCTURE?
```

If anyone has input, please chime in! Thanks

Comment: Structure is a bit old now. There is fastStructure (2014) http://rajanil.github.io/fastStructure/ which is Python. Happy to do this if there's a Pythonic Bio.popgen equivalent geared for fastStructure

Comment: I’m not totally sure what you’re asking, since the current method seems to be working? Is there a reason why you need another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately found [this function](https://github.com/lvclark/R_genetics_conv/blob/master/genind2structure.R), which I used for the purpose of converting a genind to a STRUCTURE file. The graph4lg [genind_2_structure](https://rdrr.io/cran/graph4lg/man/genind_to_structure.html) command would regularly error on me (present working directory couldn't be passed as the `output` argument).